# weighting methodology. 0 sample cell merging

Tags: python, merging-data, weighting

Input DataFrame looks like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TVbb.png)

In the above case, i need to write a code saying If we have cell with sample 0, then merge it with immediate above cell, and divide the universe and allot the weight accordingly.

Final Weights - Out put data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQCeB.png)

In the above case, Universe of 1000 in two cells was added and divided to 2000 and got divided by sample of 10 ending up with weight of 200 (2000-universe/10-sample)

Need help in the above code

Comment: Don't quite understand what you're trying to do... Where does the 2000 come from?

Comment: I am trying to do weighting. I have sample and universe at certain combinations. If I do not have sample (Sample =0) at a combination, then i need to merge that respective cell Universe to closest cell and derive the weight again.  2000 is Universe column got added as there is no sample in second row. Universe and sample got added and then derived the weight by dividing 2000 with 10.

Comment: Perhaps a larger samples with more examples would help make it clearer

Comment: Edited the input and output formats